# How to get step size of elements in a column in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table like

```
q)t
ex mo 
------
a  -10
a  -5 
a  0  
a  5  
a  10 
b  -30
b  -20
b  -10
b  0  
b  10 
b  20 
b  30
```

table gen query -

```
q)t:([] ex:(5#`a),7#`b; mo:-10 -5 0 5 10 -30 -20 -10 0 10 20 30)
```

**I'm trying to get min mo, max mo and step size of `mo by exp from t.**

Expected Output -

```
ex| min_mo max_mo  step_size
--| -------------------------
a | -10    10      5
b | -30    30      10
```

I'm not clear on how to get step size, below solution works but not optimised. Would you please suggest an optimized solution?

```
q)select min_mo:min mo, max_mo:max mo, step_size:last deltas mo by ex from t
```

Comment: I don't know if you're going to find anything much more optimal. The only thing I could suggest is that if you're only going to consider the last delta, then there's no need to calculate all of the deltas. You could just calculate the last delta: ```select min_mo:min mo, max_mo:max mo, step_size:abs(-).-2#mo by ex from t```